# custom fittype with two expressions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to make a custom `fittype` using two related expressions:

`(f1/(1+ksv1*Q))+(f2/(1+ksv2*Q)) == I/I0` and `f1 + f2 == 1`.

I made a `fittype` using the first expression and for now have `f1` and `f1` set to be defined manually with the `'problem'` argument. Obviously, fitting with them as plain coefficients doesn't result in `f1 + f2 = 1`.

Is there a way to add this second condition to the fittype?

```
Q = [ 0; 1; 10; 21;];
I = [ 2376.4; 2148.6; 1000.8; 736.52;];
% (f1/(1+ksv1*Q))+(f2/(1+ksv2*Q))== I/I0
g = fittype('2376.4*((f1/(1+ksv1*Q))+(f2/(1+ksv2*Q)))','dependent',{'I'},'independent',{'Q'},'problem',{'f1','f2'}','coefficients',{'ksv1','ksv2'});
myfit = fit(Q,I,g,'problem',{.23,.77})
plot(myfit,Q,I)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up plugging the second expression into the first and setting upper and lower bounds for the coefficients.

```
Q = [ 0; 1; 10; 21;];
I = [ 2376.4; 2148.6; 1000.8; 736.52;];
% (f1/(1+ksv1*Q))+(1-f1/(1+ksv2*Q))== I/I0 ; f1+f2=1, f2=1-f1 ; I0 = 2376.4
g = fittype('2376.4*((f1/(1+ksv1*Q))+((1-f1)/(1+ksv2*Q)))',...
        'independent',{'Q'},'dependent','I')

myfit = fit(Q,I,g,'lower',[0 0 0],'upper',[1 inf inf]) % bounds for [f1 ksv1 ksv2]
figure
plot(myfit,Q,I)
```